# Difference between {% block javascripts %} and {% javascripts %} in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I just started using Twig instead of PHP templates and I've seen that people sometimes use

```
{% block javascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

and sometimes

```
{% javascripts %}
{% endjavascripts %}
```

are these two equivalent? which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% javascripts %}
{% endjavascripts %}
```

is related to assetic library

```
{% block javascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

is just a random block named javascripts

more here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html